# Adding another box to an existing column using Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I currently have a `Bootstrap` grid that looks as follows:

[image]

The code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <h1>Box 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div id="left-panel"  class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                    Box 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right-panel" class="col-6">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                       Box 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to add a Box 4 to the grid, as seen below:

[image]

How would I amend my code to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls Check below one,we used nested div :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid border border-dark text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <h1>Box 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row border border-dark">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div id="left-panel col-12 border border-dark"  class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="align-self-center border border-dark">
                    Box 2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="left-panel-1 col-12 border border-dark"  class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="align-self-center border border-dark">
                    Box 4
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right-panel" class="col-6 border border-dark">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                       Box 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This output does not address the question asked.  Notice that Box 4 in my screenshot 
 is directly *underneath* Box 3 (whereas your Box 4 is to the *right* of Box 3)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have updated code as same as requirement ,please check